# firebase query inside functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

```js
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.pushNotification = functions.database.ref('/cancelledClasses/{dsd}').onWrite(change=> {
   var test=change.data;
   var ids=["505050","121212"];
   const message = change.after.val();
   var tokens=[] 
   var rootSnapshot = change.after.ref.parent.parent;
   for(i of ids){
   rootSnapshot.child("usersToken/"+i).once("value",snapshot => {
    if (snapshot.exists()){
        newArray.push(tokens.child("token").val());
    }})}

        var payload = {
            
                "notification":{
                    "click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
                    "title":"From: Mr." + message.senderName,
                    "body":message.course+" Class has been cancelled !",
                    "sound":"default",
                    
                    },
                "data":{
                    "sender": "Mr." + message.senderName,
                    "click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
                    "title": message.course + " Cancelled Class",
                     "body": " The class of "+message.day + " has been cancelled."
                }
        }      
            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(newArray, payload).then((response) => {
                console.log('Pushed notifications');
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            })
})
```

could you please tell me how to query those data? I have an array of ids and I want to pick their tokens from usersToken document… here is my code and database[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qv8DI.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWcnP.png)

Comment: Please paste the code here, for a better debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need create a promise, collect it,  and run it not in the loop.
like https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/Node-8/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js#L51